# How can I login PuTTy using root

Tags: root, putty

when I use putty login my server, I get access denied with the user: root

Comment: Is remote root login enabled?  I personally think having root access enabled is a bad idea.  You haven't said what OS & release you are referring to.

Comment: I am usung window 10, server is ubuntu18.04, I can login as my username and type su - to change to root, but my friend said need a true root, he want to login putty using root, I don't know how to do.

Comment: Have you created/enabled the 'root' account?  By default root is disabled.  If it is enabled, have you setup passwordless-login (ie. using keys)?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Restart SSH server to apply changes:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Problem solved, thanks:)

Comment: To anyone wanting to use this from a windows machine: prepare for a hacked system in the future. root and admin/sudo passwords need to be kept on the system itself and never ever ever ever be used to connect to a server. -never-. Take security serious. You create a different user to connect to a server. And elevate permissions when the user is on the server with a different password check

Comment: Thanks for the remind.